# Empty Lambda vs Null Reference Check C#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, nullreferenceexception

I recently made a pull request on Mahapps Metro regarding a potential null reference exception

The situation was this

```
    Action cleanUpHandlers = null;
    var cancellationTokenRegistration = DialogSettings.CancellationToken.Register(() =>
         {
             cleanUpHandlers();
             tcs.TrySetResult(ButtonStyle == MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative ? MessageDialogResult.Affirmative : MessageDialogResult.Negative);
         });
     cleanUpHandlers = () => {...
```

You can see that if `DialogSettings.CancellationToken` is cancelled before `DialogSettings.CancellationToken.Register()` it tries to call `cleanUpHandlers()` which is null.

My proposed fix

```
Action cleanUpHandlers = new Action(()=>{});
```

My question is this a better/worse solution then

```
    var cancellationTokenRegistration = DialogSettings.CancellationToken.Register(() =>
         {
             if(cleanUpHandlers != null) cleanUpHandlers();
             tcs.TrySetResult(ButtonStyle == MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative ? MessageDialogResult.Affirmative : MessageDialogResult.Negative);
         });
```

or C#6

```
    var cancellationTokenRegistration = DialogSettings.CancellationToken.Register(() =>
         {
             cleanUpHandlers?.Invoke();
             tcs.TrySetResult(ButtonStyle == MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative ? MessageDialogResult.Affirmative : MessageDialogResult.Negative);
         });
```

I think there fairly close equivalents and be it my own project I wouldn't post the question but my first contribution to a project like this and want to make it right

Comment: I'd say it's worse. There are patterns for invoking event handlers and it's reasonable to expect those will have `null` values. You should stick to those patterns where possible.

Comment: Yes, the version where you're new'ing up the empty delegate *is* worse as you're incurring an additional delegate allocation. You could get around this with a `static readonly Action NoOpAction = () => { }; Action cleanUpHandlers = NoOpAction;`, but that makes for somewhat untidy code. Null check is a neater choice.

Comment: I updated my Pull Request to a `cleanUpHandlers?.Invoke()`